# CakePHP email - Call to a member function subject() on a non-object

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

My application sends emails fine on local (using amazon ses), but fails on remote (a digitalocean server with a barebones LAMP).

The following code yields the message in the title of this question.

```
public function test() {
            $this->autoRender = false;
            App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
            $email = new CakeEmail('transport');
            $email->template('welcome', 'default')
                    ->emailFormat('both')
                    ->to('recpt@domain.com')
                    ->from('sender@domain.com')
                    ->subject(__('A subject'))
                    ->send();
}
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you try with just `'A subject'` instead of `__('A subject'))` in the subject ?

Comment: Nope. If I remove that line completely the error becomes "Call to a member function from() on a non-object"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of your calls in the Chain will return a string instead of the CakeEmail object.

This happens if for various reasons the parameters of the call become `null`. Then your chain is broken and you will end up calling a member function on a non-object;

If you look at the return value for those functions you will see they either return the CakeEmail object, a string or an array. Since you're not getting an object, you must be getting the string or the array and hence your problem.

So make sure that your 'to', 'from' are NOT empty on the remote server.

Comment: Thank you. An exemplary answer in explaining the internals of the chain.